# .net framework 4 redistributable

Tags: .net

Just wondering where we can get .net framework 4 beta redistributable.
We would like to include it in our cd so we can distribute it to our clients and they need to install it from the cd and not from web as it is not necessary to have internet for our application.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks
Navin

Comment: only the beta is currently available

Comment: Yup i know that but i am wondering if i can download it so i can ship it in my cd rather than having my users to download via internet.
Thanks

Comment: You want to ship a product built on a beta framework to your users? Somehow I don't think that's a very good idea.

Comment: .net 4 Beta 2 has an explicit go-live license from Microsoft for production use. That still doesn't make it a good idea to ship it to costumers (it's more intended for ASP.net Apps), but it's not against the TOU either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the beta is currently available: [.NET Framework 4 Beta 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ded875c8-fe5e-4cc9-b973-2171b61fe982&displaylang=en)

There is also a cut down version that may be sufficient for most applications: [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile Beta 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=68a7173d-7ee5-4213-a06f-f2e943ec9249&displaylang=en)